# C++ operation overload, crash

Tags: c++

Why does this code crash the program when I run it

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& cout, Array<int> a) {

    return cout;
}
```

and this doesn't

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& cout, Array<int>& a) {

    return cout;
}
```

Comment: How do you run it? Could you post a little context? What is Array?

Comment: You have to show what is Array! Most probably you are allocating memory, and you have no copy constructor plus the destructor deallocates that memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the copy constructor for `Array<int>` do ? See if reading the first answer to [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) solves your problem (namely, that your class handles internally a pointer to a resource, but fails to perform a deep copy in its copy constructor, resulting in two instances deleting the same resource).

Answer (score 1):

The overwhelming probability is that your `Array<int>`'s copy constructor or destructor are screwed. In addition to that, you've got some serious namespacing problems- you've used namespace std for the ostream, but then called your argument cout, which is a conflict with std::cout. I'm amazed this code compiles- you should always use std:: for Standard names, because otherwise is just ambiguous.

Comment: There's no conflict: arguments shadow global and member variables with the same name silently.